# Qt6 Tooltips and dropdowns are shown in wrong screen

Tags: c++, qt

I have three screens: one from Laptop (index 1) and two external monitors (indexes 3 and 2):
The display at the center is the main display:

[image]

I have a very basic Qt 6.2.4 application created from scratch. The `main.cpp`, `mainwindow.h` and `mainWindow.cpp` files were not changed, only the `ui` file `mainwindow.ui`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>107</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox">
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>RGB8</string>
         </property>
        </item>
        <item>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Mono8</string>
         </property>
        </item>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
        <property name="toolTip">
         <string>This is the tooltip of this button</string>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Hover to see tooltip</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item>
     <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
       <size>
        <width>20</width>
        <height>40</height>
       </size>
      </property>
     </spacer>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionFirst_option"/>
    <addaction name="actionSecond_option"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuHelp">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Help</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionAbout"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
   <addaction name="menuHelp"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
  <action name="actionFirst_option">
   <property name="text">
    <string>First option</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionSecond_option">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Second option</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionAbout">
   <property name="text">
    <string>About</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

When the application is in the screen at the center (3), the dropdown are shown in another screen (2):
[image: app in screen 3, dropdown in screen 2]
When the application is in the screen at the left, the dropdown are shown correctly:
[image: app in screen 1, dropdown in screen 1]

The same happens with any tooltip.

Qt 6.2.4 was compiled locally with Visual Studio 2019

The same issue happens if I reorder the screens (1,2,3) or I disable the screen 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved in Qt 6.5.1. So I'm closing this question.

Comment: What about `Qt 6.5.2.0`?  I facing the same issue as like you in `QT6.5.2.0`